# what's wrong with my mysqli join statement syntax

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM 'category' JOIN 'post-item' ON category.category-id = post-item.category-id");
```

1 post-item can have 1 category and 1 category can have many post-item.

Comment: is it giving error or returning nothing?

Comment: no error, echo $result but returned nothing

Comment: just check mysql error log, or just print the query and copy it run it on phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
SELECT * FROM 'category' 
JOIN 'post-item' ON category.category-id = post-item.category-id"
```

to

```
SELECT * FROM `category` 
JOIN `post-item` ON `category`.`category-id` = `post-item`.`category-id`
```

You have single quote which is not correct

Comment: doesn't work. `post-item`.`category-id`? are you sure?

Comment: $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM `category` 
JOIN `post-item` ON `category`.`category-id` = `post-item`.`category-id`");

echo $result;

Comment: can u post ur table and data in http://sqlfiddle.com/ the query should work if it has data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify particular fields because with * it cannot recognize which fields to fetch and from which table.
So do it something like

```
"SELECT table1.field1, table1.field2, table2.field4 FROM category JOIN post-item ON category.category-id = post-item.category-id"
```

Also you can leave out ` or ' while querying through PHP except when you are supplying dynamic variable.